# Communicate between pods in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have something like this:

```
           POD-1
             |
 -------------------------
 ?|?        ?|?        ?|?
service-1 service-2 service-3
```

How do I communicate from a server inside a pod, to other servers in pods behind services?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to have services for the pod that you want to access. You can just use internal endpoints of the corresponding services of the pod.

As example let's think there is a `mysql` pod and service corresponding to it as `mysql-svc` of type ClusterIP exposing port 3306 as below.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql-svc
spec:
  ports:
  - name: db-port
    protocol: "TCP"
    port: 3306
    targetPort: 3306
  selector:
    app: mysql
```

And there is a separate pod of python application which uses that mysql. yo can access that mysql server inside pod using `mysql://mysql-svc:3306/dbName` which is the internal endpoint of `mysql-svc`

And if your pods are in two different namespaces (mysql in `dev` namespace and python app in `qa` namespace) you can use `mysql-svc.dev.svc.cluster.local` instead.

Comment: When you create a Service, it creates a corresponding DNS entry. This entry is of the form <service-name>.<namespace-name>.svc.cluster.local, which means that if a container only uses <service-name>, it will resolve to the service which is local to a namespace. 
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/#automatic-labelling

Answer (score 7):

If you have another service with pods, you can simply access by using the cluster internal DNS:

For service `foo` in namespace `bar` the url is `foo.bar.svc.cluster.local`. The last part `cluster.local` can change based on how you deployed the cluster. `kops` lets you specify different values for it.

When communicating within the same namespace, you don't even need `bar` you can just do `http://foo/` or `foo:port` with different protocols (like mongo/rabbit/postgrest etc)

Comment: Is this a good practice? Asking because there are also tools like Istio and so on (no experience with them)

Comment: Isitio can also be used with this kind of cluster local DNS. In production you probably want to use a better service layer that can do proper load balancing.

Answer (score 1):

The pods on the other namespace in the same cluster can be reached with just the **svc-name.namespace-name**

SVC Name: foo

Namespace Name: bar

eg: foo.bar

Answer (score -1):

If you want to communicate internally within cluster without exposing to internet HTTP/HTTPS i would suggest you to deploy an nginx pod with nodeport and then provide your config in this nginx pod to route your request based on paths for each service. Refer: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/#exposing-the-service

To access from internet refer https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/

Alternatively you could just run each service on different nodeport as explained in https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/service-access-application-cluster/#creating-a-service-for-an-application-running-in-two-pods

Comment: The first part is incorrect - you don't need an nginx pod to communicate internally within the cluster.

Comment: All you need is a service like mentioned at the end

Comment: @codebreach you do if you want to call one endpoint and path based routes as shown in his diagram. without that u will end up calling diff services on diff ports.